# How to print a series of strings using a for loop

Tags: c++, arduino

I am an Arduino beginner and I was wondering if there is an easy way to print a sequence of messages to a LCD display. An example of what I want to do is below.

```
    char x1 = "hello"
    char x2 = "world"
    char x3 = "hi"

    for(int z = 1; z <= 3; z++){
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print( *x1 then x2 then x3*)
    }
```

Comment: `char x1 = "hello"` You know this is wrong, right? I guess you mean `std::string x1 = "hello"` and then just do: `x1 + x2 + x3`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not put a string in a char variable, you can however create a null terminated C string as follows:

```
char* x1 = "hello";
char* x2 = "world";
char* x3 = "hi";
```

then you can print them individually or if you want to use a for loop, place them in an array as follows:

```
char* sentence[3];

sentence[0] = "hello";
sentence[1] = "world";
sentence[2] = "hi";
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(sentence); i++)
{
// words will be displayed one at a time
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);   
  lcd.print( sentence[i]);
}
```

Comment: this will work, thank you. However, is there any way to display a variable by combining two strings. (sorry about my terminology I'm really new to this)

E.g. 

       lcd.print( "x" + "1") will print x1

Comment: No, but Serial.print("x"); followed by Serial.print("1") would print both together.

Comment: @Andre Medina The + operator works as a concatenation on std::string variables as mentioned by DimChtz if you are free to use the standard library you can substitute char* with std::string